# collapsing all other menu when one is expanded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on react js and I make a dashboard with sidebar(sidenav) in my sidebar I have a menu with submenu's And I want the collapse menus automatically when I click on one of the menus to be opened

```js
          <div className="main-menu">
            <ul>
              {MenuItems.map((menuItem, key) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={key}
                  name={menuItem.name}
                  iconName={menuItem.iconName} 
                  subMenu={menuItem.subMenu || []}
                />
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const MenuItem = (props) => {
  const { name, subMenu, iconName } = props;
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  return (
    <li onClick={props.onClick}>
      <a
        href="#"
        onClick={() => {
          setExpand(!expand);
        }}
        className={`menu-item ${expand ? "active" : ""}`}
      >
        <div className="menu-icon">
          <span>{iconName}</span>
        </div>
        <span>{name}</span>
      </a>
      {subMenu && subMenu.length > -0 ? (
        <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand ? "active" : ""}`}>
          {subMenu.map((menu, index, to) => (
            <li key={index} className={`${expand ? "active" : ""}`}>
              <Link to={menu.to}>{menu.name}</Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : null}
    </li>
  );
};
export default MenuItem;
```

Comment: Let the parent component control which `MenuItem` component should be opened / closed.

Answer (score 0):

If the subMenu prop has an id or a unique value, you can add another variable which will be the opend subMenu id

something like:

```
  const [opendMenuId, setOpendMenuId] = useState(null); // no menu is open by default
```

and for the className

```
 {subMenu.map((menu, index, to) => (
 <li key={index} className={`${opendMenuId === menu.id ? "active" : ""}`}>
   <Link to={menu.to}>{menu.name}</Link>
 </li>
)}
```